# Convert string value to widget in flutter

Tags: string, flutter, widget, converters

I have color value Color(0XFFDDDDDD) stored as a string in my database. I want it to convert to Color widget in flutter. How can I do it?
[Here is image of flutter color value picked from color picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQwE2.png).

I tried spliting the string to remove Color() and to take 0XFFDDDDDD value but it didnt't worked. I want to be able to use this string value to color value like: Container(color: Color(0XFFDDDDDD))

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String s = "0xffdddddd";
Container(color: Color(int.parse(s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the Hex colour string

```
 String color = "Color(0XFFDDDDDD)";
 String hex = color.substring(0, color.length - 1);
 hex = hex.substring(6, hex.length);
```

Parse it to a color: `Color(int.parse(hex));`

Ideally, your hex colour should also be saved as a pure hex colour in the DB so that you do not have to format the string unnecessarily.

Btw if the parsing doesn't work try this extension:

```
extension HexColor on Color {
  /// String is in the format "aabbcc" or "ffaabbcc" with an optional leading "#".
  static Color fromHex(String hexString) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }

  /// Prefixes a hash sign if [leadingHashSign] is set to `true` (default is `true`).
  String toHex({bool leadingHashSign = true}) => '${leadingHashSign ? '#' : ''}'
      '${alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```